# Why is Object moving by its own?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity3d,
I want my platform to move on the x-axis only,
but when I run the game I can see changes of both x and z directions instead of moving left, the object moves left and up.

This is my code:

```
    protected virtual void Update () {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * (objectSpeed * Time.deltaTime));}
```

If I apply this code on a simple cube it works fine (left only),
but when I apply it on my object- it goes left and up. Here is my object:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that there is another force acting upon your object?

Comment: Does it move left+up "indefinitely" or does it go so far and then slow and begin to fall? It's possible that your object, if placed on top of another object, is bouncing.

Comment: There is no other force.  It goes left and up non-stop until you can't see it on the screen.  I want it to go just left

Comment: What is the type of `objectSpeed`?

Comment: Is there also a rotation? As you haven't set the coordinate space the translation will be in the transform's local axes.

Comment: it's a float and it's = 1

Comment: There is no rotation

Comment: Sorry, your post is impossible. You are moving it from somewhere else. Check Rigidbody, check other scripts. Start commenting scripts until you find the bad one

Comment: I don't have any other scripts or rigidbody, thanks anyway

Comment: I posted it because it's "impossible". I don't understand your comment

Comment: comment that line and check if the object is still moving

Comment: Typo. I meant to say that what you have in your question cannot possibly happen. Create new scene then attach that script to an empty object. Only the X axis will be moving!

Comment: @Lestat Gave up that advice too but he didn't listen. By commenting stuff, OP should find the fix

Comment: I listened I did it and it stopped moving at all

Comment: Perhaps your gravity is set to a negative number, making things float?  You really should add more to this question - the sheer number of comments asking for more info should make it clear that the scope of the issue is beyond what you've posted.

Comment: I updated my question with a picture.  The problem is with my object, not the script

Comment: Post the complete code!

Comment: It is the complete code- there is only an Update method and 3 floats. I just checked this code on a new object (a cube) and it worked perfectly! The code doesn't work well with my "stone_bridge" object only (I attached the picture). I also tried to disconnect it from the prefab.

Comment: I'm not sure if set data breakpoints, but if you can, breakpoint the z axis of the transform and follow the stack trace to see why it's moving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `transform.Trnaslate` to move your object. It uses the default value for `relativeTo`, which is `Space.Self`. This means, that it will transform the object's position relative to it's rotation. Your object has slight rotation on y axis, that causes the problem. Either set `relativeTo` to `Space.World` or set the object's rotaiton to 0.

Here is more information in [Unity Documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)

Comment: This is true. The default is self and OP rotated the GameObject a little bit.

Comment: Thanks David!  I added `Space.World` to the Translate function and it solved the problem (both of your solutions worked).